# Expression / idiom / slogan to say you will be in advance of the others in global competition

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests, slogan

Is there an expression/idiom/slogan to say :

> "thanks to us you will be in advance of the others (in technology/business)".

I was thinking of "Be ahead of" or "Get ahead of", but i don't know which words using after :

- Be/Get ahead of the World
- Be/Get ahead of the Game
- Be/Get ahead of the Curves
- Be/Get ahead of the Competition

Edit : Is there a difference using "Get ahead of" instead of "Be ahead of" ?

Comment: “... of *others*”, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

The idiom 'have the edge over someone' would do nicely in your sentence.

> thanks to us you will **have the edge over the others** (in technology/business)

You can hear the sound of axes being ground for battle!